# Updating a Model Form Class with Form Values in Django

Tags: python, django, database, forms, model

I am populating a Model class object with values submitted via a form. The form, of type ModelForm, is mapped to the model class. The form can be updated by a user and needs to update the same record in the database. How can I update the Model class object with new values submitted via the form without having to explicitly overwrite each Model class field? Is there an easier, more elegant way to do this in Django? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you just save the content from the form? That should update your db, right?

Comment: Are you using an updateview for that??